# Is there a way to consistently reference-capture a returned variable and use it in a destructor when the return type is movable?

Tags: c++, caching, return, c++20, move-semantics

I've been working on adding transparent result-caching functionality to some computationally intensive code with multiple return statements.  Whenever the function returns for any reason I want to take the last known value of the working buffer (`val` in the code below) and put it into a cache so I don't need to calculate it again in the future.  Here's a basic reproduction of what I'm attempting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

struct ScopeExit
{
    ScopeExit(std::function<void()> f) : m_f(f) {}
    ~ScopeExit() {m_f();}

private:
    std::function<void()> m_f;
};

std::map<int, std::string> g_cache;

std::string func(const int key)
{
    std::string val;

    if (g_cache.contains(key))
    {
        // returning from the cache like this does NOT work
        return g_cache.at(key);

        // assigning the cached value to 'val' prior to returning DOES work
        //val = g_cache.at(key);
        //return val;
    }

    val = "hello world";

    // add the result to the cache just before we give the result to the caller
    ScopeExit scopeExit1([key, &val](){
        auto [iter, inserted] = g_cache.try_emplace(key, val);
        if (inserted)
            std::cout << "inserted \"" << iter->second << "\" into cache for key = " << iter->first << std::endl;
    });

    // normally a bunch of math happens here but I'm using a string for this example

    std::ranges::fill(val, 'b');

    if (2 == key)
        return val;
    
    std::ranges::for_each(val, [](auto& v){v += 1;});

    return val;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = func(1);
    auto b = func(2);

    // these should pull from cache
    auto c = func(1);
    auto d = func(2);

    std::cout << "key = 1: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "key = 2: " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "key = 1 (cached): " << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "key = 2 (cached): " << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Ma314evhb

I noticed that when it was returning from the cache directly (e.g. `return g_cache.at(key);`), all cached values were empty, as if they had been moved from prior to the `scopeExit1` destructor code running.

```
inserted "" into cache for key = 1
inserted "" into cache for key = 2
key = 1: ccccccccccc
key = 2: bbbbbbbbbbb
key = 1 (cached): 
key = 2 (cached):
```

Further research led me to the "automatic move from local variables and parameters" section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return, which I believe states (**paraphrased** - please correct me if I'm wrong):

> if *expression* is a non-volatile object type declared in the body, it will treat the return value as an rvalue expression and pick the move constructor if available, otherwise it will treat *expression* as an lvalue and pick the copy constructor.

I wrote an instrumented version of the same thing here: https://godbolt.org/z/6xrdTddsM, which confirms that the move constructor is being called on return and that it's being accessed afterwards.

```
(0x7ffe1bf1f330) default constructor
(0x7ffe1bf1f410) move constructor (source = 0x7ffe1bf1f330)
(0x210dee8) copy constructor (source = 0x7ffe1bf1f330)
inserted "" into cache for key = 1
(0x7ffe1bf1f330) destructor

(0x7ffe1bf1f330) default constructor
(0x7ffe1bf1f3f0) move constructor (source = 0x7ffe1bf1f330)
(0x210df38) copy constructor (source = 0x7ffe1bf1f330)
inserted "" into cache for key = 2
(0x7ffe1bf1f330) destructor

(0x7ffe1bf1f330) default constructor
(0x7ffe1bf1f3d0) copy constructor (source = 0x210dee8)
(0x7ffe1bf1f330) destructor

(0x7ffe1bf1f330) default constructor
(0x7ffe1bf1f3b0) copy constructor (source = 0x210df38)
(0x7ffe1bf1f330) destructor

key = 1: ccccccccccc
key = 2: bbbbbbbbbbb
key = 1 (cached): 
key = 2 (cached): 
(0x7ffe1bf1f3b0) destructor
(0x7ffe1bf1f3d0) destructor
(0x7ffe1bf1f3f0) destructor
(0x7ffe1bf1f410) destructor
(0x210df38) destructor
(0x210dee8) destructor
```

Interestingly, if I replace the `return g_cache.at(key);` with `val = g_cache.at(key); return val;` it elides the move and constructs the string in-place in the caller's stack and works the way I want.  However, because I don't think this elision is mandatory (I'm not returning prvalues) I think it only coincidentally works, although the undefined behavior sanitizer doesn't appear to mind.

Side questions: Is this actually consistent / guaranteed / well defined behavior?  And if so, is there any way to make it less fragile from a maintainability point of view? (e.g. I added a different return variable and oops I unknowingly completely broke caching)

```
(0x7ffee22bc150) default constructor
(0x1c1dee8) copy constructor (source = 0x7ffee22bc150)
inserted "ccccccccccc" into cache for key = 1

(0x7ffee22bc130) default constructor
(0x1c1df38) copy constructor (source = 0x7ffee22bc130)
inserted "bbbbbbbbbbb" into cache for key = 2

(0x7ffee22bc110) default constructor
(0x7ffee22bc110) copy assign (source = 0x1c1dee8)

(0x7ffee22bc0f0) default constructor
(0x7ffee22bc0f0) copy assign (source = 0x1c1df38)

key = 1: ccccccccccc
key = 2: bbbbbbbbbbb
key = 1 (cached): ccccccccccc
key = 2 (cached): bbbbbbbbbbb
(0x7ffee22bc0f0) destructor
(0x7ffee22bc110) destructor
(0x7ffee22bc130) destructor
(0x7ffee22bc150) destructor
(0x1c1df38) destructor
(0x1c1dee8) destructor
```

I also noticed that it works the way I want if I comment out the move constructor and move assignment operators - this lets it fall back to the copy constructor according to the `return` rules quoted above.  This approach seems to be a consistent and correct way to achieve what I want, but isn't very practical in my actual application where I'm working with `std::vector<float>`.

Is there any way to ensure that my returned variable will not be moved from so that I can use it in my scope exit destructor?

Comment: Since you're caching each `result` prior to returning could you not return a `const` reference instead?

Comment: @WBuck the caching is technically happening in a destructor that runs after the return statement is processed so no, not with the current approach.  I could change the function to emplace the working buffer (i.e. `val`) into the cache (when it doesn't find an entry at that key) and then do all the math there, which would let me then always return a const ref to the cached entry.

Comment: If you're dead set on using `ScopedExit` then you could instead capture `val` by value . For example: `ScopedExit scoped( [ key, val ]( ){ }`. This way the lambda has its own copy of `val` which is safer than capturing it by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to ensure that my returned variable will not be moved from so that I can use it in my scope exit destructor?

Yes: make a copy of it when you try to return it. Turn all of your `return a;`s into `return std::string(a);` or [whatever type you're using](https://godbolt.org/z/rKqEMzWj1).

A much easier solution is to properly separate your concerns. You need a function which computes a value, and you need a function that deals with the cache. Your problem comes from trying to do both in the same function.

So... don't do that:

```
std::string uncached_func(const int key)
{
    std::string val = "hello world";

    // add the result to the cache just before we give the result to the caller
    ScopeExit scopeExit1([key, &val](){
        auto [iter, inserted] = g_cache.try_emplace(key, val);
        if (inserted)
            std::cout << "inserted \"" << iter->second << "\" into cache for key = " << iter->first << std::endl;
    });

    // normally a bunch of math happens here but I'm using a string for this example

    std::ranges::fill(val, 'b');

    if (2 == key)
        return val;
    
    std::ranges::for_each(val, [](auto& v){v += 1;});

    return val;
}

std::string cached_func(const int key)
{
    //If you use `contains` followed by `at`, you're doing it wrong.
    if (auto it = g_cache.find(key); it != g_cache.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    auto ret = uncached_func(key);
    //No point in `try_emplace`, because it obviously wasn't cached if we're here.
    g_cache.emplace(key, ret); 
    return ret;
}
```

Indeed, you can move `cached_func` [into a generic type that also stores its own cache](https://godbolt.org/z/arvxEqaPz). This allows you to avoid relying on a global variable which *will* bite you when someone eventually tries to thread this code:

```
template<typename> class CachedAccess;

template<typename Ret, typename Arg>
class CachedAccess<Ret(Arg)>
{
private:
  std::map<Arg, Ret> cache_;
  std::function<Ret(Arg)> callable_;

public:
  explicit CachedAccess(std::function<Ret(Arg)> callable) : callable_(callable)
  {}

  Ret operator()(Arg arg)
  {
    if (auto it = g_cache.find(arg); it != g_cache.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    auto ret = callable_(arg);
    g_cache.emplace(arg, ret); 
    return ret;
  }
};
```

Comment: @Jarod42: Fixed.

Comment: thanks - you're definitely right that separation of concerns makes this easier.  The only thing I'm still curious about (from an academic standpoint) is why the compiler elided the move when all the return statements returned the same variable.  Is this just an optimization that I can't rely on or is it a case where elision is guaranteed?

Comment: @plexik: That's just named return value optimization. And no, it's not guaranteed, but one of the conditions most compilers require is that all control paths return the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

I assume since you're caching the values that performance matters to you, so constantly copying `std::string`'s is probably not what you want to do in this case.

For example, this line here: `return g_cache.at(key);` will always copy construct the `std::string` (assuming the return type of the function is by value).

I also find the use of the `ScopeExit` to add unnecessary complexity to your situation and will force you to capture the `std::string` by value or explicitly copy construct a new `std::string` when returning.

Also, you ideally don't want a global cache as that can get you in to trouble with multi threaded code.

That being said, in keeping with your current design (having a global cache and caching the value in the `func` function) here is a more efficient way you can accomplish what you're after.

```
static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> cache{ };

static const std::string& get_value( int key ) 
{
    if ( auto it{ cache.find( key ) }; it != std::end( cache ) ) 
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    
    std::string value{ "Some complex computed value" };
    const auto[ it, _ ]{ cache.insert( { key, std::move( value ) } ) };
    return it->second;
}
```